# How do you write the sql to delete a line from a database in a detailsView control using VB?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Using a DetailsView control on a web page coding in VB.Net Framework 4.5.2 on Visual Studio (Think its VS 2014).  Need it to delete an item from a database (.mdf file format).  The database is provided by the class, but the auto generation option for the Edit, Delete, and New keys is locked out for some reason.

I have the Edit, and New buttons working, as I could get that out of the book and it was easy to adjust them for this database.  What I can't get to work is the line for delete.  Here is what I have (Adjusted from the book I'm using):

```
DELETE FROM Schedule WHERE (ID = @ID)
```

When I go to debug it, I get the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Post your code where you use `SqlCommand`.

Comment: yes - that variable is not declared - it should be the primary key value you are trying to delete.

Comment: I have to use the database given by the class.  The table doesn't have the primary key on it, or related to it at all.  How would I assign a key to this ID value?

Comment: @Dai, I used the DetailsView Tasks window from design view.  Open the Configure Data Source window.  On the Configure the Selected Data part, I have to select the radiobutton for specifying custom SQL Statements.  What I posted was the line I have right now in the Delete part of the next window.

I don't know how to find the SqlCommand part.  The code in the HTML part is this though:

'<DeleteParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
 </DeleteParameters>'

Answer (score 0):

```
dim cmd as new sqlcommand("Delete from tablename where ID=@id",constring)
cmd.parameters.add("@id", idno.text)
cmd.executenonquery
```

This is how u should do it